# AngularJS - Turn ng-controller name into a directive variable

Tags: angularjs

**If I have a div inside a directive template with an attribute value to a ng-controller, how can I change that into a variable:**

```
original html : <div ng-controller="HomeController"> ..... </div>

directive: <my-directive some-var-name="HomeController"> ....</my-directive>
```

---

```
.directive('MyDirective', function(){
  return {
   .....
   scope:
   {
     someVarName : "????"  <-- what type? "=", "@", "&" : none seem to work
   },
   template: '<div ng-controller="someVarName">.....</div>'      
   }
   });
```

**Thanks Mark for solving this:**

```
    <select-add-new  select-model="$parent.selectedFrontAxle" text="add new" 
             select-phrase="Front Axle Type" preselected-filter="Front" 
             label-name="Front Axle" open-dialog="Front" 
             select-options="axleTypes" var-ctrl="AxleTypesCtrl"></select-add-new>

  .directive('selectAddNew', function () {
   return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: "E",        
    scope: {
        selectModel: "=",
        selectOptions:"=",
        labelName: "@",
        preselectedFilter: "@",
        selectPhrase: "@",
        text: "@"
    },
    compile: function(tElement, attrs) {
        var div = tElement.find('#ctrlId');
        div.attr('ng-controller', attrs.varCtrl);
    },
    template: '<div>' + 
              '<div class="local-label">{{labelName}}: </div>' +
              '<name-value-select-control  select-phrase="{{selectPhrase}}" selected-item="selectModel" preselected-filter="{{preselectedFilter}}" options="selectOptions"></name-value-select-control>' +
              '<div id="ctrlId">' +
              '<div txt-add-new text="{{text}}" action="openDialog(\'Front\')" style="display: inline-block"></div>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>'
};
```

})

---------------------------------------------Mark------------------------------------------------------

**Here's the plunker:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/b6G2y3yqjhxpu059ZrWB

**Here is the problem:**

I combined two directives into one super directive. If you go to app.js, directive 'selectAddNew', thrid line from the bottom you will see:

.........     action="openDialog(\'Front\')"   ..................

But that is hard coded. I tried every which way to make it an action in the super directive but the closest I came was the common dialog opening a window of the entire form. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your dialog issue as a separate question (as it is not related to the title of this question).  When you create a new question, please explain where you are trying to get "openDialog" from.

Comment: OK, I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254239/angularjs-create-dynamic-action-in-super-directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template is compiled during the compile phase, at which point `someVarName` is not available (it is a property of the directive's scope, which is not set up yet).  Instead, in the compile function, we can add an `ng-controller` attribute to the `div`, and set it to the value of the `some-var-name` attribute:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>....</div>',
        compile: function(tElement, attrs) {
            var div = tElement.find('div');
            div.attr('ng-controller',attrs.someVarName);
        }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/XERTZ/)

Comment: What if I had more than one div in that template, how do I identify the div which should have the controller? Think I found the answer:                   var div = tElement.find('#findme')  --> correct?

Comment: You have a couple of options: you can use children(), next(), or jQuery selectors to find the target div in the template;  you could append() or prepend() the div that should have the controller; you could have the compile function create the entire template.

Comment: You are a FREAKIN genius, you know that? I hate you are so smart ;)

Comment: Mark, can you hang close? I got one more small issue and this entire project is done. I will post an addendum at the top explaining last issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for @: `scope:{someVarName:'@'},template:'<div>Hello {{someVarName}}</div>`

Comment: Appreciate your help OP but that won't help, someVarName is a controller and you have it outside the html element. That won't do.