# AngularJS - Create dynamic action in Super Directive

Tags: angularjs

**I have a super directive made up of 2 directives. The second "child" directive is a add-new open dialog control:**

Here is the plunker:

**http://plnkr.co/edit/b6G2y3yqjhxpu059ZrWB**

If you examine the super directive "selectAddNew", third line from the bottom, you will see this code:

```
 <div txt-add-new text="{{text}}" action="openDialog(\'Front\')" style="display: inline-block"></div>
```

The problem is **action="openDialog(\'Front\')"** is hard coded.

The super directive's html is this:

```
  <select-add-new  select-model="$parent.selectedFrontAxle" text="add new" 
       select-phrase="Front Axle Type" preselected-filter="Front" 

       label-name="Front Axle" open-dialog="Front" <------ need to pass this value

       select-options="axleTypes" var-ctrl="AxleTypesCtrl"></select-add-new>
```

I can live with the method OpenDialog, if I have too, but the paramater \'Front\', needs to get it's value from this part of the Html above:

```
          open-dialog="Front"
```

**Initially I tried this (making it an method action):**

```
open-dialog="openDialog('Front')"
```

**With this in my directive:**

```
    .directive('', function(){
        ..........
        scope: {
        open-dialog: "&"
    },
        ......      
    },
    template: .....
             '<div txt-add-new text="{{text}}" action="openDialog()" style="display: inline-block">
             ......
 };
```

But I found myself in an endless loop when reviewing the code in Chrome console

Comment: Where is `openDialog()` defined?  Directive `txtAddNew` uses `&` which means it is trying to call the expression assigned to attribute `action` on the parent scope.  I think (not sure) that a method named `openDialog` has to be defined on the scope associated with directive `selectAddNew` for this to work.  Unless you use `$parent.$parent` or something.

Comment: It is defined in the AxlesCtrl, I tried to post that snipet in Plunker but I got script errors as it is dependent on outside code. Can we just assume the method exists elsewhere and is valid? I just want to pass a dynamic parameter. openDialog is a method call from 3rd party script.

Answer (score 3):

**Mark I solved it, code below:**

```
     <select-add-new  select-model="$parent.selectedFrontAxle" text="add new" 
             select-phrase="Front Axle Type" preselected-filter="Front" 
             label-name="Front Axle" dialog-param="openDialog('Front')" 
             select-options="axleTypes" var-ctrl="AxleTypesCtrl"></select-add-new>

.directive('selectAddNew', function () {
return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: "E",        
    scope: {
        selectModel: "=",
        selectOptions:"=",
        labelName: "@",
        preselectedFilter: "@",
        selectPhrase: "@",
        text: "@",
    },
    compile: function(tElement, attrs) {
        var div = tElement.find('#ctrlId');
        div.attr('ng-controller', attrs.varCtrl);
        var div2 = tElement.find('#OpenWindow');
        div2.attr('action', attrs.dialogParam);
    },
    template: '<div>' + 
              '<div class="local-label">{{labelName}}: </div>' +
              '<name-value-select-control  select-phrase="{{selectPhrase}}" selected-item="selectModel" preselected-filter="{{preselectedFilter}}" options="selectOptions"></name-value-select-control>' +
              '<div id="ctrlId">' +
              '<div id="OpenWindow" txt-add-new text="{{text}}" style="display: inline-block"></div>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>'
};
```

[image]