# pass dynamic controller to angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am familiar with the syntax of **controller** & **name** but i'm trying to create a generic directive that will get a list of items and for each item i need to specify a controller.

This is my main directive:

```
function controlPanel() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            controlPanelItems: "=sbControlPanelItems"  
        },
        templateUrl: 'control-panel.html',
        link: link
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element) {
    }

}
```

Here is the directive template:

```
<sb-control-panel-item ng-repeat="controlPanelItem in controlPanelItems"
                                         sb-title="controlPanelItem.title"
                                         sb-template-url="controlPanelItem.templateUrl"
                                         sb-control-panel-item-controller="controlPanelItem.controller"></sb-control-panel-item>
```

My issue is with the **sb-control-panel-item-controller** attribute.

Angular throws exception when i'm passing variable, it work's great when i'm passing simple string (the name of the controller).

Here is the code of the control-panel-item directive:

```
function controlPanelItem() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            title: '=sbTitle',
            templateUrl: '=sbTemplateUrl'
        },
        templateUrl: 'control_panel_item.html',
        controller: '@',
        name: 'sbControlPanelItemController',
        link: link
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, iElement, iAttributes, controller) {

    }

}
```

Maybe there is a way to inject the controller through the link function and then i'll just pass it through the scope?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253317/angularjs-turn-ng-controller-name-into-a-directive-variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the $controller service to instantiate whatever controller dynamically inside the directive, check this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/9JEGum0zLYCWCfP1KRDC?p=info).
Just bear in mind that if you wanted to specify a controller statically now, you would need to enclose it in single quotes.

Basically the code would be like:

```
function MainCtrl() {
  this.firstCtrl = 'FirstCtrl';
  this.secondCtrl = 'SecondCtrl';
}


function FirstCtrl() {
  this.name = 'First Controller';
}

function SecondCtrl() {
  this.name = 'Second Controller';
}


function fooDirective() {
  return {
    scope: {
      ctrl: '='
    },
    template: '<div>{{foo.name}}</div>',
    controller: ['$controller', '$scope', function($controller, $scope) {
      var foo = $controller($scope.ctrl, {$scope: $scope});
      return foo;
    }],
    controllerAs: 'foo',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {
      console.log($scope.ctrl);
    }
  };
}

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .directive('fooDirective', fooDirective)
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
  .controller('FirstCtrl', FirstCtrl)
  .controller('SecondCtrl', SecondCtrl);
```

and this would be the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <h1>
      Test
    </h1>

    <foo-directive ctrl="main.firstCtrl">
      "name: " {{foo.name}}
    </foo-directive>


    <foo-directive ctrl="main.secondCtrl">
      {{foo.name}}
    </foo-directive>
  </body>

</html>
```

**========================================================================**
**WRONG OLD ANSWER**

From [this blog entry](https://toddmotto.com/dynamic-controllers-in-directives-with-the-undocumented-name-property/) seems to be an undocumented property that allows you to do exactly what you need.

```
function FirstCtrl() {
  this.name = 'First Controller';
}

function SecondCtrl() {
  this.name = 'Second Controller';
}

function fooDirective() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    name: 'ctrl',
    controller: '@',
    controllerAs: 'foo',
    template: '<div></div>',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {

    }
  };
}

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .directive('fooDirective', fooDirective)
  .controller('FirstCtrl', FirstCtrl)
  .controller('SecondCtrl', SecondCtrl);
```

So all you need to do in your directive is add a property name linked to the attribute you will use with the name of your controller.

```
<foo-directive ctrl="FirstCtrl"></foo-directive>
<foo-directive ctrl="SecondCtrl"></foo-directive>
```

If your directive, as per your question, needs to be from a property rather than a string, use {{}} notation:

```
<sb-control-panel-item ng-repeat="controlPanelItem in controlPanelItems"
                                         sb-title="controlPanelItem.title"
                                         sb-template-url="controlPanelItem.templateUrl"
                                         sb-control-panel-item-controller="{{controlPanelItem.controller}}"></sb-control-panel-item>
```

Comment: You may want to read my question again,  as i mentioned  i am familiar with the name property, the problem is when i'm trying to pass a variable and not  a string.

Comment: Use {{}} notation in the attribute, sorry I misread your question.

Comment: Can you add a working jsfiddle? Try to do it and still get an exception

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't work like that, I have changed the answer with a plunkr attached.